# input number for currency with kendoNumericTextBox

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm doing a view with kendo in that view the user should put the amount of his expenses but my view doesn't accept values with decimal numbers !  i.e if i put for example 12 it's okey but if i put 12.256 it shows me an exception !!

I want to accept values like: 12.250 0.120 ....

This is My view:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <label class="cke_label" for="Montant">Montant Recette</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <input type="number" required="" style="text-align: right; width: 100%; background-color: inherit;" placeholder="Montant" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="100" class="currency" id="Montant" name="Montant">
    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Montant" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      Montant.value = $("#Montant").kendoNumericTextBox({
        format: 'n3',
        toFixed: '3',
        value: "0.000",
        min: "0",
        step: "0.001"
      }).data("kendoNumericTextBox");
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

This is my controller:

```js
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "EncaissementID,libelle,DateEncaissement,Montant,ProjetID,Description")] Encaissement encaissement) {
  encaissement.Montant = Convert.ToDecimal(encaissement.Montant);
  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    db.Encaissements.Add(encaissement);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Encaissement");
  };
  ViewBag.ProjetID = new SelectList(db.Projets, "ProjetId", "nomP");
  return View(encaissement);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You question is a bit ambiguous about the format you are looking for (Do you want a comma or a dot as decimal separator).

Basically, the first thing you need to do is to include the culture js file:

```
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/js/cultures/kendo.culture.en-US.min.js"></script>
```

If you want the dot as an input, you can use `kendo.culture.en-US.min.js` or if you want to use the comma, you can use `kendo.culture.fr-CA.min.js`.  Those are only example... you can take pick any other culture file base on your location.

Then you need to tell kendo which culture he should use by passing the culture to the `kendo.culture` function:

```
kendo.culture("fr-CA");
```

You can refer to [kendo's number formatting documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/numberformatting) for more detail about how kendo is handling number formatting.

Comment: your answer really helped me ! but where should i exactly put the culture

Comment: even after when i added the cultrule js it didn't work !! and it still accepts just int numbers when i put for exemple 12.258 it shows me a message (you should enter a valid value the nearest ones are 12 and 13 ...) i tried to add this pattern pattern="(\d{3})([\.])(\d{2})" but the problem is not solved

Comment: my model state is not valid !! even when i converted it " encaissement.Montant = Convert.ToDecimal(encaissement.Montant); " it didn't work

Comment: I updated my answer.  Pay attention to `kendo.culture`.  Also, note that the kendoNumericTextBox object was assigned to `Montant.value`.  I updated the code to use the value of the kendoNumericTextBox instead.